# Need to Render 100k+ list at a time React

Tags: reactjs

When we render all the list at a time the browser is getting lagged

We are trying to render a chart with 100k+ item in an array, where all the items in the array should display in the chart.

Is there is any best way to do it in React

Comment: Please don't use words that are only used around India

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using **Lazy loading** like https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

but don't recommend showing such a huge set of data at once, what you can do is to have **pagination**, both **client-side** and **server-side** pagination.

for a line chart with huge data set, please consider using canvasjs https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/performance-demo-chart/

Comment: it is not a list, it is a chart (Line chart). for example, we need to show all the records from the year 2000 to till date in a single view. what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use react virtual list, it will render only visible items.
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: all the items in the array should display in the chart in a single view, but react-virtualized does not do it.

Comment: then probably it depends on chart library you use. it has nothing to do with react